# How to Install "Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)" on Windows Server 2003 R2?

Tags: .net, oracle11g, windows-server-2003, oracleclient, odac

I recently installed "[32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html)" on my computer (Windows 7, 64bit). Everything seems fine and I can develop and run my application in Visual Studio 2010 and IIS 7.

Now, when I deploy my application to the Server, it raises error:

> Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand' threw an exception. 
>       ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Obviously I need to install ODAC on the server, too. My server is:

- Windows 2003 32 bit R2 (I know, I know!)
- IIS 6

So. I downloaded the same installation from Oracle website (ODAC 11.2 Release 5 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio [11.2.0.3.20]) and installed it on the server. But still getting the same error.

PS: When I was installing, I chose **Oracle Data Access Component for Oracle Client 11.2.0.3.20** in Oracle Universal Installer. hmmmm. Should I choose "Oracle Server" instead?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option (Oracle Data Access Component for Oracle Client 11.2.0.3.20) worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but for other users who might face similar problem here is a post for details instruction

http://www.codewithasp.net/2012/06/step-by-step-instructions-to-install.html